# How to get Nokogiri to work with Warbler/JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, nokogiri, warbler

I'm trying to get a stand-alone jar file of a Ruby application that uses Nokogiri.

I have a Gemfile that looks like this:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'nokogiri'
```

and in bin/jartest.rb I have this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
puts "Hello world"
```

When I run:

```
jruby bin/jartest.rb
```

everything works great, but when I run

```
warble; java -jar jartest.jar
```

I get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- isorelax
```

I found "[Question on Warbler and Nokogiri](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/866277)", but I don't know where to find those jar files and I don't really want to have them in my lib directory if I can help it. Really I just want to get it working.

```
dan$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin10.0]

dan$ gem list | grep nokogiri
nokogiri (1.5.5, 1.5.0, 1.4.4)
```

Comment: What version of JRuby? What version of Nokogiri? Does Nokogiri work in irb? Does everything work locally prior to warble?

Comment: hey, have you solved this problem? I have java nokogiri version, but still my bundle doesn't use this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've installed the Java version of Nokogiri instead of the native version:

```
> gem list noko 
nokogiri (1.5.0) 
> gem install nokogiri Successfully
installed nokogiri-1.5.0-java
1 gem installed 
> gem list noko 
nokogiri (1.5.0 java)
```